# combinatorics equality proof

Tags: combinatorics

if $k , n ,q $ are  positive integers and $n \geq k $. I want to prove that:

$ {\begin{bmatrix} n+1 \\ k \end{bmatrix}}_q =   {\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}}_q + q^{n+1-k} {\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k-1 \end{bmatrix}}_q$ .

I think it may done buy using **schur theorem**.

Comment: Could you explain your notation? What do the square brackets mean and subscripts mean?

Comment: it means Gaussianorq-binomial coefficient

Comment: Using the Wikipedia article [Gaussian binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) what have you tried so far?

Comment: Which [Schur's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem) are you refering to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonathan Azose’s [senior thesis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/216832411.pdf) [PDF] at Harvey Mudd College, *Applications of the q-Binomial Coefficients to Counting Problems*, using a combinatorial interpretation of the $q$-binomial coefficients, equivalent to [the one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#Combinatorial_description) in Wikipedia, gives a straightforward proof (p. $8$). It also has a great many other standard results.

If you want to try it yourself using the combinatorial interpretation in Wikipedia, consider separately the words of length $n+1$ with $k$ ones that begin with $0$ and the words that begin with $1$; these two subsets are ‘counted’ by the two terms on the righthand side of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, for a strictly algebraic proof:
$$
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\def\qbinom(#1,#2){\left[#1\atop #2\right]_q}
\qbinom(n+1,k)
  &=\frac{(q^{n+1}-1)(q^{n}-1)\cdots(q-1)}{(q^k-1)\cdots(q-1)(q^{n-k+1}-1)\cdots (q-1)}
\\\\&=\frac{(q^{n+1}\color{red}{-q^{n-k+1}+q^{n-k+1}}-1)(q^{n}-1)\cdots(q-1)}{(q^k-1)\cdots(q-1)(q^{n-k+1}-1)\cdots (q-1)}
\\\\&=\frac{(q^{n+1}\color{red}{-q^{n-k+1}})(q^{n}-1)\cdots(q-1)}{(q^k-1)(q^{k-1}-1)\cdots(q-1)(q^{n-k+1}-1)\cdots (q-1)}
\\\\&\quad+\frac{\cancel{(\color{red}{q^{n-k+1}}-1)}(q^{n}-1)\cdots(q-1)}{(q^k-1)\cdots(q-1)\cancel{(q^{n-k+1}-1)}(q^{n-k}-1)\cdots (q-1)}
\\\\&=\frac{q^{n+1}-q^{n-k+1}}{q^k-1}\cdot \qbinom(n,k-1)+\qbinom(n,k)
\\&=q^{n+1-k}\cdot \qbinom(n,k-1)+\qbinom(n,k)
\end{align}
$$